# How to see the diff when removing superfluous blank lines

Tags: feature-request, edits

I was reviewing the edits on Stack Overflow and I stumbled multiple times on edits like this:

[image]

But I can't see what has been changed.

Comment: Personally, I'd reject the edit as "no improvement whatever"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Markdown view of the diff instead of the rendered view:

[image]

as that shows you better what has changed.

I've rejected the suggested edit.

Comment: How did they get past the six-letter threshold (and for which *most* whitespace does not count)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q it looks like that is a regression nobody noticed until now, with the introduction of CommonMark. The reality is that this 6-char limit restriction was (partly?) undone somewhere in 2017. Investigation is under way, so I'm told.